# Get user selected NSFont using NSFontManager - Unable to override changefont function

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsfontmanager

I'm trying to allow the user to select a font of his/her choice using the NSFontManager. I could show the font picker using the following code

```
@IBAction func fontchangeclicked(_ sender: Any) {
            NSFontManager.shared.orderFrontFontPanel(nil)
    
        }
```

But the NSViewController is unable to recognise this overridden function.

```
override func changefont(_ sender: Any?) {
        guard let fontManager = sender as? NSFontManager else {
                    return
                }
                let newFont = fontManager.convert(self.globalfont)
                self.globalfont = newFont
       
               }
```

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Willeke How do i get the user selected font?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list of requirements:

1. It's `changeFont` instead of `changefont`.
2. `NSObject.changeFont(_:)` is deprecated, use `NSFontChanging.changeFont(_:)` instead.
3. The view controller must adopt `NSFontChanging`.
4. Your `changeFont(_:)` is not called when the first responder object handles `changeFont(_:)`.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSFontChanging {

    func changeFont(_ sender: NSFontManager?) {
        guard let fontManager = sender else {
            return
        }
        let newFont = fontManager.convert(self.globalfont)
        self.globalfont = newFont
    }
               
}
```